# jqunit, testing regex fails at some point, why?

Tags: javascript, regex, unit-testing

I am working on testcases regarding reular expression with the assisstance of jqunit:

```
test("Date entry should be a Date", function () {
    ok(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g.test("10.12.2014"), "Date is not parsed correctly: 10.12.2014");
    ok(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g.test("10-12-2014"), "Date is not parsed correctly: 10-12-2014");
    ok(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g.test("10/12/2014"), "Date is not parsed correctly: 10/12/2014");
});
```

The second condition is failing, but executing them in the browser's console or on [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/)
all of them a true. Any hints where this behaviour comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `g` flag in a regex when you only use `test` : it doesn't make sense and, more importantly, it makes it an iterator whose result changes with each call to `test` and I guess the literal regexes are used more than once in jqunit.

Change

```
/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g
```

to

```
/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/
```

Comment: It does not make sense to change your code just to make a test happy. We write code to solve a problem. We do not write code for the tests. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851583/js-regex-match-one-or-multiple-occurences/25851775#25851775

Comment: @JoeFrambach Do you notice the regular expression is called with the `test` function (which is a standard JavaScript function, it has no link with any test unit system) ?