# JS Regex: match one or multiple occurences

Tags: javascript, regex

At the end of the day I need to regex match multiple or single occurences of a date string.

For the single ocurrence of "12-2-2014" the regex `/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/` will do.

For testing "12-2-2014 22-05-2033", it will fail. With the the global flag active, it will test positive, but I recently learned the hard way, that when using the global flag, I am not able to unit test my regular expressions.

Any help appreciated...

EDIT:  I am testing with QUnit for now. A simple test case would be:

```
 test("REGEX TEST", function () {
        var dates = ['12-2-2014', '14-5-2014'],
            regex = /(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g;
        ok(regex.test(dates.join(' ')));
        ok(regex.test(dates.join(' ')));
        ok(regex.test(dates.join(' ')));
        ok(regex.test(dates.join(' ')));
    });
```

-> I am getting different results for each evaluation...

Comment: Well, the problem doesn't seem to be here but in the way you do your unit testing. You can't refuse to use the g flag in regular expression just because you have a problem in the testing system.

Comment: What do you mean by "when using the global flag, I am not able to unit test my regular expressions"? Can you give an example of why that is the case?

Comment: Are you sure you will not be able to unit test it with the _regex_ global flag? It's entirely different from global _variables_...

Comment: it would be better if your regex is `\d{1,2}[-\/.]\d{1,2}[-/\.]\d{4}`. BUt it isn't solves your actual prob.
`

Comment: [It's obviously related to this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667268/jqunit-testing-regex-fails-at-some-point-why) but it also obviously needs clarification.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this would not be better, as I am expecting also string like "2012-11-14" :)

Comment: you failed to mention this in your question.

Comment: @chrispolzer It looks like you're trying to unit test the regular expression. This is wrong. What you should test is **your function** using the regular expression. When you're at the right level, there's no problem with the regular expression hidden in your function having the g flag.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your other question, and here is my solution which allows you to keep your flag.

```
test("Date entry should be a Date", function () {
    ok("10.12.2014".match(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g).length == 1, "Date is not parsed correctly: 10.12.2014");
    ok("10-12-2014".match(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g).length == 1, "Date is not parsed correctly: 10-12-2014");
    ok("10/12/2014".match(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g).length == 1, "Date is not parsed correctly: 10/12/2014");
});
```

Here are more tests I came up with:

```
test("Invalid dates should be rejected", function () {
    ok("10#12#2014".match(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g).length == 0, "Date is not parsed correctly: 10#12#2014");
    ok("September".match(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g).length == 0, "Date is not parsed correctly: September");
});


test("Multiple Dates should be found", function () {
    ok("10.12.2014 11.13.2015".match(/(\d+[-/\.]\d+[-/\.]\d+)/g).length == 2, "Date is not parsed correctly: 10.12.2014 11.13.2015");
});
```

Comment: No, this confuses the problem. The test unit should test his code, not his regex.

Comment: Are you sure you had this tested? Because the String object has the method `match()` ...

Comment: Of course I don't test my SO answers :) I've updated it.

Comment: @dystroy The test should reflect what is done in the application code. I assume the application should fetch the dates from the string. The test should do the same.